# Change height of one of multiple fields in stack view

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout

In my code I have a stack view that initially has 1 element `PhoneNumberField`. Another `PhoneNumberFields`can be added dynamically in the runtime:

```
@IBAction func addAlternatePhoneNumberAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let alternateNumberView = PhoneNumberField()
        ...
        phoneNumberStackView.addArrangedSubview(alternateNumberView)
    }
```

This is what xib for `PhoneNumberField`looks like: 
[image]

The problem is that I would like to be able to dynamically hide the 'Name for other phone' field based on the content of 'Mobile combobox'. When I set the 'isHidden' parameter everything works as expected, the only problem is that the `PhoneNumberField` height stays the same. I would like it to shrink when the 'Name for other phone' field is hidden.

I tried doing it using the outlet for height constant for `otherNumberNameField` in the `PhoneNumberField.swift` file  but the problem is that in that case all of the `PhoneNumberFields` in the stack view have the size of the first field.

What would be the correct solution for this?

edit: In addition to the answer below: I had to set the distribution for the phoneNumberStackView to `equal spacing`. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Try edited answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create StackView.

Don't set its height constraint, just set top, leading, trailing and bottom constraints. 
Bottom constraint set equal to Error label top constraint.

Then set its distribution to **Fill Equally**.

[image]

Now put first two Views into one view and put this view together with OtherNumberField view to this StackView.

So now your hierarchy should look like this:

[image]

Now when you hide one view from StackView, StackView will be smaller because you didn't set its height.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. The `PhoneNumberField` doesn't change size after hiding the field.

Comment: Yeah, the `SubStackView' height is set to be in certain ratio to the error label so how could it change to be smaller?

Comment: @MartaPanuszewska because items in SubStackView are fill equally. If you hide item in stack view, all other items will try to take place of this hidden item equally

Comment: @MartaPanuszewska ok, I edited my answer, try it now. It should be easier way

Comment: Robert, I might have not explained myself correctly. When I hide the `OtherNumberField` I don't need the the `View` (`MobileComboBox` + `NumberField`) to become bigger. I need the whole `PhoneNumberField` (so, the stack view) to become smaller. So I would like the `PhoneNumberField` to change its size from approximately 134 points (2 fields + label) to 78 points (1 field + label).

Comment: Thank you for all your help though, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @MartaPanuszewska ok, I think I finally understood your question. So try edited answer now.